# unable to install libpython3.4-dev under ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python3

I need to install pyephem for python3, so I did

```
sudo python3 setup.py install
```

in the folder where I untar the pyephem package.

It gives error message "file not found"

```
 #include "Python.h"
                ^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

after searching, it appears that i need to install python3.4-dev, but again :

```
Les paquets suivants contiennent des dépendances non satisfaites :
 python3-dev : Dépend: libpython3-dev (= 3.4.0-0ubuntu2) mais ne sera pas installé
               Dépend: python3.4-dev (>= 3.4.0-0~) mais ne sera pas installé
E: Impossible de corriger les problèmes, des paquets défectueux sont en mode « garder en l'état ».
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: http://rhodesmill.org/pyephem/#installation suggests using `pip` to install `pyephem`. Any reason why you didn't want to do that?

Comment: When using pip, it installs pyephem under python 2.7, and I need it also under python 3.4

Comment: You need to use `pip3` to install Python 3 packages.

Comment: I tried with pip3, but still the same problem ...

Comment: How about trying `sudo apt-get install python3-dev`?

Comment: Same problem ...